# R ggplot custom label axis ticks with other variable

Tags: r, ggplot2

When labelling axis ticks I'd like to add other information from the dataframe in parentheses. For example, using code snippet below I'd like to automatically include the information on `Area` in parentheses next to the label `X`. In other words, the label might say 'Chicago (45)' instead of just 'Chicago'. I know I can do this manually by setting labels in `scale_x_discrete`. However, can I do this automatically? My dataset has a large number of entries so I would like to avoid doing this manually.

```
dataset <- data.frame(Area = sample(c(NA, 1:100), 3, rep = TRUE),
                      Y = rnorm(3), X = c("Chicago","New York", "Orlando"))
ggplot(dataset, aes(X, Y)) + geom_point()
```

Comment: You could do something like this on the fly: `aes(paste0(X, "\n(", round(Area), ")"), Y)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build a new column with your desired ticks labels:

```
library(dyplr)
library(stringr)
library(ggplot2)
dataset = dataset %>% mutate(label = str_c(X, " (", Area, ")"))
```

Then use the column label in the aesthetics

```
ggplot(dataset, aes(label, Y)) + geom_point()
```